# dynamic menu in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to write a code that creates Menus based on user Role.

```
Dim User_Role As String = "Admin"
Dim Menus As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
    {"Admin", { {"item1", "item1_icon" }, {"item2", "item2_icon"}, {"item3", "item3_icon"} } },
    {"User", { {"item1", "item1_icon" }, {"item2", "item2_icon"} } }
}
For Each menu As Object In Menus.Item(User_Role)
    'Inside this loop i need to get for example "item*" and "item*_icon" each time until all items in that user role are looped through and idk how to do it
Next
```

Where i am getting things wrong?

[Here's the expected result with "Admin" user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APavn.png)

[And this is expected result with "User"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it8VZ.png)

Comment: Instead of `Object`, use a `List(Of Class)` or an array of named tuples (`(Item As String, ItemIcon As String)()`). Or whatever other concrete type that fits.

Comment: Hey, @Jimi  thanks for your comment. I was wondering how do i do that? I'm new in VB.NET

Comment: It's hard to tell from the image what kind of control that is.  For instance, if they are PictureBoxes, then you'd use `List(Of PictureBox)`.  A Label?...then `List(Of Label)`.  Or maybe it's a custom class, put the name after `Of`.  If you're creating those with the `New` keyword it should be obvious.  If you're using some kind of `Add` method then it's probably the return type of that function.

Comment: @Idle_Mind The controls are buttons and i need to store each button's (name and icon) as strings in the dataset.
Here's the idea: I have variable Role = "Admin" and then when i Loop through Menus[Role] with each iteration i need to get result of array(name, icon) and then i'll use that as button.text = array(0), and button.image = my.resources(array(1)) to create dynamic menu of buttons based on roles.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now.

Use this syntax:

```
Dim User_Role As String = "Admin"
Dim Menus As New Dictionary(Of String, String(,)) From {
    {"Admin", {{"item1", "item1_icon"}, {"item2", "item2_icon"}, {"item3", "item3_icon"}}},
    {"User", {{"item1", "item1_icon"}, {"item2", "item2_icon"}}}
}

Dim menuSystem As String(,) = Menus.Item(User_Role)
For row As Integer = 0 To menuSystem.GetUpperBound(0)
    Console.WriteLine(row & ": " & menuSystem(row, 0) & ", " & menuSystem(row, 1))
Next
```

Output:

```
0: item1, item1_icon
1: item2, item2_icon
2: item3, item3_icon4
```